# How to make npx work with my custom npm pakage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, npx

I've published a new package which aims to generate a very small boilerplate for a node open source project via cli. For now, it's just a combination of few npx commands and requires other npm packages like gitignore, license to work. I want to execute the build script in package.json with the following command.

```
npx get-set-node-oss build youremailaddress@xyz.com
```

Link to the npm package: [get-set-node-oss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-set-node-oss). I know the name is a bit too long.

```
{
  "name": "get-set-node-oss",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "One command setup for your Node OSS project",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx license mit > LICENSE && npx gitignore node && npx covgen"
  },
  "author": "Harshit Juneja",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/harshitjuneja/get-set-node-oss.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "boilerplate","gitignore","MIT","OSS"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/harshitjuneja/get-set-node-oss/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/harshitjuneja/get-set-node-oss#readme"
}
```

I expect the user to make a new folder and cd into the folder and do

```
npx get-set-node-oss build emailstring
```

and get the resulting boilerplate files.

Comment: Is it recommended to include an entry point, even in case it doesn't serve any purpose(as in my case)?

Answer (score 2):

For npx to work you need to specify what the `get-set-node-oss` command means. Thankfully, this can be accomplished by using the `bin` field in your package.json file. More information from NPM documentation for your [reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin):

> To use this, supply a bin field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local installs.

An example of it below.

```
"bin": {   
    "get-set-node-oss": //script you like to run
},
```

Hope it works out for you. I have understood bin as scripts in package.json. Where we can either do `npm run foo` or `npx foo` both yielding the same results. If you want an example, here you go https://github.com/vipulgupta2048/balenaclone